# Clearing rules in Security Group

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm trying to clear the rules out of a security group using RevokeSecurityGroupIngressRequest but I keep getting the exception "Missing source specification: include security group or CIDR information" yet I am including the security group ID so not sure what I am doing wrong here...

```
var client = new AmazonEC2Client(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(awsRegion));

var revokeRequest = new RevokeSecurityGroupIngressRequest();
revokeRequest.GroupId = sgID;

try
            {
                var revokeResponse =     client.RevokeSecurityGroupIngress(revokeRequest);
            }
            catch (AmazonEC2Exception ex)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error clearing the SG" + ex);
             }
```

I am hoping I don't have to list each IP address, I just want an easy way to clear all the rules out of the SG, although it's not too much of a problem if I do have to input the IP addresses to move.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to list each, because `RevokeSecurityGroupIngress` interprets this value missing in the request as no rules being specified, instead of all rules being specified.

You'll need to include a collection of [IpPermission](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TEC2IpPermission.html) in the [RevokeSecurityGroupIngressRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TEC2RevokeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.html).

The easiest way to list all rules for removal:

- Call DescribeSecurityGroups and from [DescribeSecurityGroupsResponse](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TEC2DescribeSecurityGroupsResponse.html) get the `IpPermissions` collection from `SecurityGroup`.
- Build a new RevokeSecurityGroupIngressRequest with the name of the security group and the IpPermissions collection from above.
- Call RevokeSecurityGroupIngress with this request.

Answer (score 0):

> yet I am including the security group ID

The id of the group you're trying to modify?  That's not what the error is about.

> Missing source specification: include security group or CIDR information

The *source* CIDR spec or the *source* security group ID is required -- ingress security groups can authorize traffic based on whether it originates from an instance that is a member of a specific security group, and this is the "security group or" that is mentioned in the error.  You have to identify the rule you want to remove.